# Enctype not working on MAC browsers

Tags: html, forms, enctype

This is strange, but I have a web form in one of my sites that uploads files correctly on Windows browsers but not on Mac browsers and I'm pretty confident it has to do with the Enctype.  I've stripped the form down to it's bare parts (pretty awkward...) and still no luck.

Here's the form header:

```
<form ENCTYPE='MULTIPART/FORM-DATA' METHOD='POST'>
```

You can assume the html body tags are correct.  The form has a close tag in the right place and the doctype is set to strict.  There is no javascript interfering with the form either.

Anyone experience something similar?

Comment: You need to share the whole form, and explain in more detail what you expect will happen, and what actually happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known bug in Safari/Mac OS X going back several years, apparently. In some cases Safari doesn't close the network connection after uploading a file. So the upload effectively fails.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5760

There may be a workaround in this thread:
http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-672301.html